¿Como resuelvo este problema de iteraciones?
Debo hacer un programa en python 2 para la facultad con la siguiente consigna.
Escriba un programa que solicite al usuario un número entero n y a continuación imprima un triángulo tal como se indica en los ejemplos de ejecución. El valor de n máximo posible será 9.
El ejemplo que me dan es el siguiente:
Ingrese altura del triangulo:
   3
  2 2
 1 1 1

yo utilice el siguiente código:
n = int(raw_input("Ingrese altura del triangulo:"))
print
if n<=9:
   for i in range(n, 0, -1):
       print " " * (n-i),
       for j in range(i):
           print i,
       print

pero el resultado me da un triangulo invertido.
 Ingrese altura del triangulo: 3

 3 3 3
  2 2
   1

¿Como puedo solucionarlo? Muchas gracias

Solo hay que usar la lógica de impresión de forma inversa. El primer print señalizado hace que se imprima la cantidad máxima de espacios y luego va disminuyendo. Contrario al segundo for que empieza en range(1) y va aumentando. Además cambié la variable j por _ ya que su valor no se usa.
n = int(raw_input("Ingrese altura del triangulo:"))
print
if n<=9:
   for i in range(n, 0, -1):
       print " " * (n+i), # <-- Cambio
       for _ in range(n-i+1): # <-- Cambio
           print i,
       print

No está de más decir que, a menos que sea por una situación obligada de mantener algún sistema, mejor aprendas con Python 3.x, preferiblemente >= 3.9. La versión 2.x está obsoletísima y la 3.x ha incorporado muchas mejoras, como manejo nativo utf-8, formateo de cadenas, operaciones asíncronas, integración con módulos de 3ros como IA y análisis de datos, etc.
